# Quiero hacer un programa que el usuario seleccione un item de un combobox y según lo que seleccione devuelva otros datos a un textfild

Tags: java, netbeans

He creado un jframe form y quiero que en un combobox se seleccionen unas medidas y en un jlabel o combobox entregue otras medias que corresponden a esa primera medida.Alguien sabe como se hace eso?Muchas gracias

if(btn_medidas.getSelectedIndex() == 0){ btn_respuesta.setSelectedIndex() == 0; } //losbtn son combobox en el btn respuesta quiero que selecione una opcion por ejemplo la opcion 2 del combobox que le he escrito ya cuando s selecione una opcion en el primer combox cambie en el segundo

Comment: Comparte el código que tienes por favor.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask].

Comment: if(btn_medidas.getSelectedIndex() == 0){

        btn_respuesta.setSelectedIndex() == 0;
} //losbtn son combobox en el btn respuesta quiero que selecione una opcion por ejemplo la opcion 2 del combobox que le he escrito ya cuando s selecione una opcion en el primer combox cambie en el segundo

Answer (score 0):

Para saber que elemento de una ComboBox es seleccionado, puedes utilizar esta sentencia:

```
//cmbbx= Es el nombre de tu comboBox
if(cmbbx.getSelectedIndex() == 0){
       //Y aquí es donde mandas que quieres que suceda si escoge este elemento
}
```